# char pointer- How can I debug this code?

Tags: c, variables, pointers, char

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char *p, *initial;
    int c, in=0;

    for(initial=p; (c = getchar()) != EOF; p++, in++)
        *p = c;

    for(int i=0; i<in; i++)
        printf("%p = %c\n", initial, *initial++);
}
```

For an input like `hello hai`, the program gives incomplete output:

```
0028FF29 = h
0028FF2A = e
0028FF2B = l
0028FF2C = l
0028FF2D =  
0028FF2E =  
0028FF2F =  
0028FF30 =  
0028FF31 =
```

It is working fine for small text, but it's not working for large text.

Comment: `p` is a pointer to an unallocated memory space .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undefined behavior. You don't set `p` to point to any valid memory location. So `*p = c` does not a well defined program make.

You can either have `p` point to a fixed sized buffer (if you **know** input will never be beyond a certain number of characters):

```
char buff[MAX_SIZE];
char *p = buff;
```

Or use dynamic memory allocation:

```
char *p = malloc(INITIAL_SIZE);
size_t current_size = INITIAL_SIZE;
// Later
if (p - initial == current_size) {
  char *buff_new = realloc(initial, current_size * 2);
  if (buff_new) {
    initial = buff_new;
    p = initial + current_size;
    current_size *= 2;
  }
  else
    // should probably abort here, the program is out of memory. Bad bad bad.
}
```